# Is the Chrome feedback system part of Android?

Tags: android

In the Google Chrome app, there is a feedback button that opens a window like the one that opens when you report a force close.

I am wondering whether this is part of the Android SDK, and if so, where is the documentation on how to use it?

[image: Screenshot of what I mean]

*I posted this here as it is technically a development question*